# Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: git, setup

When I tried to set up git in my computer I encountered the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: How did you try to install git? When or in reaction to what does this error message occur?

Comment: Did you run `apt` using `sudo`?